# YAML and tuples as dict key

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, dump, python-2.x

Let

```
d = {3: u'blah', u'b': u'foo', (12,2,3) : u'bonjour'}
```

be a dictionary. If I use

```
g = yaml.dump(d)
h = yaml.load(g)
print g, h
```

it's very good, but I get lots of `!!python/unicode` everywhere, so that's not good for readability.

On the other hand, if I use :

```
g = yaml.safe_dump(d)
h = yaml.load(g)
print g, h
```

there are no-more the `!!python/unicode` but also not the `!!python/tuple` anymore, so the **`load` doesn't work because the tuple isn't understood correctly.**

**How to get the right balance with YAML ?**

- no `!!python/unicode` everywhere,
- having tuples as dict key working ! (so probably `!!python/typle` has to be kept)

Comment: I think you need to talk to PyYAML developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for [python yaml unicode](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+yaml+unicode), the very first result is [this bug report](http://pyyaml.org/ticket/11), which has exactly the solution you're looking for.  In short, register a custom *representer* for unicode strings, like this:

```
yaml.add_representer(unicode, 
                     lambda dumper, value: dumper.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', value))
```

With this in place, your example renders like this:

```
>>> d = {3: u'blah', u'b': u'foo', (12,2,3) : u'bonjour'}
>>> print yaml.dump(d)
3: blah
? !!python/tuple [12, 2, 3]
: bonjour
b: foo
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks, this is exactly what I was looking for! By the way, is there a similar way for renaming tags `!!python/tuple` to `tuple` ?

Comment: Possibly?  I have never tried writing a custom constructor.  You would need to spend some quality time with the PyYAML documentation on [representers and constructors](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers).